# Add dialog at the end of installer

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer

I have a simple Wix installer which deploy my basic application.
Until now, i used the basic UI of WiX because my installer know where install the files. But at the end of installation, i don't have a notification that indicate that the installation ended.
I would like just an pop-up or anything else which notify the user that installation is completed like an MessageBox in C# with "Installation complete" and a button OK to close.
I checked the other topic of StackOverFlow but is too complicated for my case.

Actually, i have this but i'm a bit lost:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" UpgradeCode="" Version="1.0.0.0" Language="1036" Name="Deployeur" Manufacturer="My Manufacturer Name">
    <Package InstallerVersion="300" Compressed="yes" />
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="myapplication.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="WINDOWSVOLUME">
        <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="PROJECT">
          <Directory Id="APP" Name="APPLICATION" />
          <Directory Id="FOLDERSCRIPT" Name="files" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <Feature Id="root" Title="Main" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="appli" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="folderFiles" />
    </Feature>
    <UI>

        <Publish Dialog="ExitDlg" 
            Control="Finish" />

    </UI>
    <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALTEXT" Value="Installation completed" />



  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Could you help me ?
Edit : Actual UI 
[image]

Comment: Can't you use "Minimal UI" in this case, or "InstallDir wihtout license" (see the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597025/how-to-build-a-minimal-wix-installer-ui-without-a-license-page?

Comment: Actually i have this UI for my installer. (i updated my post). I will try with your proposition.

Comment: Check out the docs (if you are using Visual Studio, you just need to add a reference): http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/wixui/wixui_dialog_library.html

Comment: I don't work with VS but i solved my problem (http://leavinsprogramming.blogspot.fr/2014/01/wix-msbuild-adding-wixextension-to-fix.html). Now i would disable path validation on my InstallDirDlg dialog, i check the documentation and i read "set the public property WIXUI_DONTVALIDATEPATH to 1" How to do this ? What "public property" ?

Comment: You can exclude the path dialog at all if you don't want it, for example by using "Minimal" API, not "InstallDir" - it comes without path selection.

Comment: For exclude the path dialog , i changed InstallDir by Minimal. Thank you :)