# custom dialog when previous version exists

Tags: wix

I want to customize my installer to show custom dialog when previous version is already installed.  After the welcome dialog user should see a custom dialog that says, "A previous version already exists do you want to continue". Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [document](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/WixUI_customizations.htm), to add Custom Dialog in standard WIX Dialogs.You can use **Upgrade** to find the previous version installed.

Set OnlyDetect attribute to yes, to avoid uninstall previous versions.

```
<Upgrade Id="{CE61D541-9988-4DA7-B748-7DF4355C6000}">
   <UpgradeVersion Property="PREVIOUSFOUND"
                   Minimum="1.0.0" IncludeMinimum="yes"
                   Maximum="$(var.Version)" IncludeMaximum="no"
                   OnlyDetect="yes"/>
</Upgrade>
```

Use **PREVIOUSFOUND** property to publish the Previous Version exists dialog from Welcome Dialog.

```
<Publish Dialog="WelcomeDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog"
         Value="PreviousVersionDlg">PREVIOUSFOUND</Publish>
```

Comment: I get: Unresolved reference to symbol 'Dialog:PreviousVersionDlg'
Any idea how to solve this? Maybe I need to add some dll to my references?